# subprocess: start process in background and start another in one call

Tags: python, subprocess, suspend

This program should echo the pid of sleep immediately:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("sleep 1 & echo $!", shell=True)
```

Running this on the shell directly, it immediately prints the pid, but running it in python, the `&` is ignored and it takes 1 second before `echo` is executed.

How can I get this to work with only one execution of `check_output` (or another function of `subprocess`)?

(This is a simplified example, in reality instead of `sleep 1` I'd put my own executable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_output` waits for the output pipes to close and `sleep` has them too. You can redirect to `/dev/null` for an immediate return.

```
subprocess.check_output("sleep 1 >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!", shell=True)
```

*UPDATE*

Its hard to tell if `sleep 1` really did run in the background so I wrote a slightly larger test.

*test.py* - writes time to `stdout` for 5 seconds

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
print('done', flush=True)
```

*runner.py* - runs the test redirecting `stdout` to a file and monitors the file.

```
import subprocess as subp
import time
import os

# run program in background
pid = int(subp.check_output("python3 test.py >test.out 2>&1 & echo $!",
    shell=True))
print("pid", pid)

# monitor output file
pos = 0
done = False
while not done:
    time.sleep(.1)
    if os.stat('test.out').st_size > pos:
        with open('test.out', 'rb') as fp:
            fp.seek(pos)
            for line in fp.readlines():
                print(line.strip().decode())
                done = b'done' in line
            pos = fp.tell()
print("test complete")
```

Running it, I get

```
td@mintyfresh ~/tmp $ python3 runner.py
pid 24353
09:32:18
09:32:19
09:32:20
09:32:21
09:32:22
done
test complete
```

Comment: Aha, that's why it blocks. It's strange though because I thought python just sends the command as a whole to shell and connect to shells output pipes. Now what I want to do is to send a few signals to my program while it's running, with redirecting all output pipes, sleep immediately stops and does not run in background. Can I achieve that somehow?

Comment: `sleep` did run to completion in the background - its just that sleeping 1 second is kinda hard to detect. Make the 60 seconds and run `ps`, you'll see it. You can redirect to other files if you want to keep the output and since `check_output` returns the pid, you have a mechanism to send signals.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write the script. This indeed shows that this works. I'm stuck with sending `SIGINT` to the process I just started (probably because of process group IDs), but I might open another question for that problem